# PHP is not generating content

Tags: php, html, generator

I would like to make a simple HTML file generator with PHP, where user inputs some data, and the .php file generates an output with HTML code, including the data from user.

The problem is that my generator generates only a blank .html file.

The form is simple:

```
<form action="html_form_submit.php" method="post">
<textarea name="name" rows="2" cols="20"> </textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/></form>
```

And the `html_form_submit.php` file:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    $name = @$_POST['name'];
?>
<html><body>
Name: <?php echo $name; ?><br>
</body></html>

<?php
    $output = ob_get_contents(); 
    $filename = 'test.html';
    !$handle = fopen($filename, 'w');
    fwrite($handle, $output);
    fclose($handle);
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Length: ". filesize("$filename").";");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; ");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    readfile($filename);
    ob_end_clean(); 
?>
```

Do you know, where can the problem be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

at html_form_submit.php file:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
}
?>
<html><body>
Name: <?php echo $name; ?><br>
</body></html>

<?php
    $output = ob_get_contents(); 
    $filename = 'test.html';
    !$handle = fopen($filename, 'w');
    fwrite($handle, $output);
    fclose($handle);
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Length: ". filesize("$filename").";");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; ");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    readfile($filename);
    ob_end_clean(); 
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for  the answer. It's working now.

Comment: One more quick question: when I generate the content, the output file sometimes doesn't contain the whole HTML code. I use there some inline css styles, images, etc..

Comment: may be somewhere the single or double quotes are not closing properly. :)

Comment: No, i found the source of the problem. I just increased the size of the buffer, so everything is ok now. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

You should move invocation of ob_end_clean immediately after the `$output = ob_get_contents();`.
ob_end_clean clears your buffer so the response comes back empty.
Try like this:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    $name = @$_POST['name'];
?>
    <html><body>
    Name: <?php echo $name; ?><br>
    </body></html>

<?php
    $output = ob_get_contents(); 
    ob_end_clean(); 
    $filename = 'test.html';
    !$handle = fopen($filename, 'w');
    fwrite($handle, $output);
    fclose($handle);
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Length: ". filesize("$filename").";");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; ");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    readfile($filename);
```